# hasClass() not working in function with variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to develop a photo gallery for a website that toggles pictures based on the taxonomy (in this case, used to describe the event the pictures belong to) they're sorted into.

I've rendered a list of the taxonomies within the archive, and used data attributes to save the taxonomy slug to be used later as a class.

```
<?php
$terms = get_terms( 'event-name' );
if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
 foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
   echo '<a href="#" class="tax-list" data-hide="' . $term->slug . '">' . $term->name . '</a> ';


 }
}?>

</div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="ms-container-photo">

<?php query_posts('post_type=photo-gallery&orderby=rand&showposts=-1'); ?>



<?php if(have_posts()): while(have_posts()): the_post();?>
<?php
  ++$counter;
  if($counter == 3) {
  $postclass = 'col-xs-6 col-sm-6';
  $counter = 0;
  } else { $postclass = 'col-xs-6 col-sm-3'; }
?>



<div class="<?php echo $postclass; ?> <?php $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'event-name' );
if ( !empty( $terms ) ){
// get the first term
$term = array_shift( $terms );
echo $term->slug;
}?> photo-gallery ms-item"><img data-original="<?php
echo types_render_field("photo-url", array("argument1"=>"value1","argument2"=>"value2","argument2"=>"value2"));
?>" class="lazy"></div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else: ?>
<?php wp_redirect(get_bloginfo('siteurl').'/404', 404); exit; ?>
<?php endif;?>
<?php wp_reset_query();?>
```

The goal is, using the links echoed at the top, to be able to hide/show the divs based on what class is added to the div below via the term(s) defining it. I've tried to use jQuery to accomplish to goal, and to be honest, am confused as to why it's not working... hoping one of you guys can help!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.tax-list').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var hideselect = $(this).attr('data-hide'); 
        var tohide = $('div.photo-gallery');

        function hidebytax() {
            if ($(tohide).hasClass(hideselect)) {
                $(tohide).addClass('pink')
            } else {
                $(tohide).addClass('blue')
            };
        };  
        hidebytax();
    }); 
});
```

For simplicity's sake, I've simply chosen to add a class (`pink` or `blue`, depending on which term is attached to `div.photo-gallery`, but when I click one the the triggering links, `pink` is always added regardless of which link in clicked, and the else statement is completely ignored.

Can someone tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: does `data-hide` gets filled anyway? Can you post a bit of the resulting html?

Comment: You should provide compiled html!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First reset the divs by removing all the pink(&blue) classes and than use the attribute as a class selector, add class `.pink` to them and optionally add `.blue` to the rest of the `.photo-gallery` divs using jquery `not()`

try:

```
$('a.tax-list').click(function(e){
         $('.photo-gallery ').removeClass('pink');
        e.preventDefault();
        var hideselect = $(this).attr('data-hide'); 
                $("."+hideselect).addClass('pink');
                //$('div.photo-gallery').not($("."+hideselect)).addClass('blue');

    });
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yb6onm12/

Comment: It's still adding `pink` to all of them, regardless of which link is triggering the event.

Comment: You're wonderful! Thank you so much for your help! And don't worry, you're getting marked as the answer ;)